# getting a notice in reports for Commerce Paypal EC. IPN for Order ignored:

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I am using [Commerce PayPal](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_paypal) and specifically the submodule for Express Checkout.

When checking the reports, I see many different IPN connections happening. the last two, the user is marked as "anonymous" instead of user name. The first is "IPN Validated..." and the second is **"IPN for Order 138 ignored: this operation was accommodated in the direct API response."**

Is this normal? Is there something in my settings that needs to be changed so it isn't "ignored"?

[image]

Comment: Have you added any new Rules recently? for example, any rule to set the order state?

Comment: i changed the default commerce order state rule to "complete" rather than "pending" But no other rules involving order state.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so in your case, it sounds like the IPN notification is being skipped because the order is already in the "complete" status.

To keep the IPN processing, you may need to keep the default "pending" status for such orders. That way, the IPN notification can mark the order as complete.

Comment: So to clarify, i might choose to create a rule that will fire on the final IPN request. That way the IPN cycle will complete then the status will change?

Comment: The IPN request is async from the payment gateway. It will normally set the order to "completed" but because the order is already in the "completed" state, it skips that.